# Grant access to all databases and their tables with Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, privileges

So I've done,

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO myuser; 
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO myuser;
```

and even

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE mydb1 TO myuser;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE mydb2 TO myuser;
```

But I'l still getting `ERROR:  permission denied` errors:

```
=> select * from language;
ERROR:  permission denied for table language
```

What I'm missing?

And for `GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO myuser`, all three of my current Postgresql databases have SCHEMA called `public`, what exactly that SQL is granting to?

Comment: Can you put more information? I've created a database and a table and, I created a user and ran the same commands on your question and worked for me.

Comment: My order is a bit different, I created all databases with the `postgres`. then in `pgsql` with `postgres`, I created `myuser` and granted as above. You must have done something more than this.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to create the table before running:

```
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO myuser;
```

or to run before creating the table:

```
alter default privileges in schema public grant select on tables to myuser;
```